# Setting Up Non-Root User and Group in Bazel oci_image with Proper Permissions

Tags: containers, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm working with Bazel to build an OCI image for a Python application, and I'm trying to configure it to run as a non-root user (mo1). While I've managed to specify this user in the Bazel `oci_image` rule, I'm encountering permission issues when the container runs.

```
oci_image(
    name = "my_image",
    base = "@python3_11",
    entrypoint = ["python", "my_app.py"],
    user = "mo1:mo1",
    # Other configurations...
)
```

However, when running the container, the mo1 user doesn't seem to have the necessary permissions to execute certain files, leading to errors like:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/services/metadata/metadata_bin.runfiles: Permission denied
```

So, how can I configure the `oci_image` in Bazel to set up a non-root user (mo1) and group, ensuring they have the correct permissions to access and run the application files?

I created this script `create_user_and_group.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
WORKDIR="rootfs"
mkdir -p $WORKDIR/etc $WORKDIR/home/<some folder>
echo "mo1:x:1000:" > $WORKDIR/etc/group
echo "mo1:x:1000:1000::/home/<some folder>:/bin/bash" > $WORKDIR/etc/passwd
tar -czf accelerate_user_layer.tar -C $WORKDIR .

genrule(
    name = "generate_user_layer",
    srcs = ["create_user_and_group.sh"],
    outs = ["user_layer.tar"],
    cmd = "(./$(location create_user_and_group.sh) && cp user_layer.tar $(location user_layer.tar))",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Using `rules_docker`

It seems that `rules_docker` had support for this. The functionality for this is now moved to `rules_distroless`.

The old way via `rules_docker` (tested with Bazel 7.0.2):

Add to your `WORKSPACE.bazel` file:

```
# This file is used for legacy dependencies that do not have Bzlmod support

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
    
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    sha256 = "b1e80761a8a8243d03ebca8845e9cc1ba6c82ce7c5179ce2b295cd36f7e394bf",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/releases/download/v0.25.0/rules_docker-v0.25.0.tar.gz"],
)
```

Note: rules_docker is deprecated now and there is no support for Bzlmod (at least it is not supported by BCR). Nevertheless, Bazel 7.x still supports the traditional `WORKSPACE` approach. Anyways we need only a few utility functions from `rules_docker`.

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//contrib:passwd.bzl", "passwd_entry", "passwd_file")

passwd_entry(
    name = "nonroot_user",
    info = "nonroot",
    uid = 1002,
    username = "nonroot",
)

passwd_file(
    name = "passwd",
    entries = [
        ":nonroot_user",
    ],
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "passwd_tar",
    srcs = [":passwd"],
    mode = "0644",
    package_dir = "etc",
)

oci_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "@distroless_SOMETHING",
    ....
    tars = [
        ":passwd_tar",
    ],
)
```

I tested a docker image build this way - but it seems not to be non-root. Maybe you get it working.

### Using `rules_distorless`

Add to your `MODULE.bazel` file `bazel_dep(name = "rules_distroless", version = "0.1.3")`

And to your `BUILD.bazel` file:

```
load("@rules_distroless//distroless:defs.bzl", "passwd")

passwd(
    name = "passwd",
    passwds = [
        dict(
            gecos = ["nonroot"],
            gid = 1000,
            home = "/nonroot",
            shell = "/usr/bin/bash",
            uid = 1000,
            username = "nonroot",
        ),
    ],
)

oci_image(
    name = "image",
    ...
    tars = [
        ...
        ":passwd",
    ],
)
```

Did also not work for me.

### Switch to a nonroot image variant

I finally switched to a non-root base image. And this worked.

```
oci_image(
    name = "image",
    #base = "@distroless_java21",
    base = "@distroless_java21_nonroot",
```

Comment: Thank you Vertexwahn, I just saw this. I tried the docker rule, didnt work. But for the distorless rule, how do you select a nonroot user?

Comment: @Khalis As mention "Did als not work for me.". I just added `passwd`to `oci_image` and hoped this make it a nonroot container. Actually, I do not know what exactly makes a container a noonroot container and if and how this can be achive with `rules_distorless` - maybe the examples can help you: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/rules_distroless/blob/main/examples

Comment: Actually, I figured out that I didnt need to create a layer to add user and group. You could simply change the user attribute to a nonroot user that exists within image. ie: user = "1000". This is the nonroot user added by default to the node base images. And for python base image, you can simply add the user attribute to user = "1000:1000".